# How to animate jquery MagicLine Navigation with different bottom border colour

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make menu animation for my website. i want to use jQuery MagicLine Navigation. take a look magicline demo : http://css-tricks.com/examples/MagicLine

there is 2 example one is normal bottom border, second is background different different colour animation on mouse hover. now what i want?  i want to use 1st demo but i want different different colour bottom border like 2nd demo..

can any one help me on this?

Comment: Have you tried something? If you have tried, provide a fiddle link with your code.

Comment: No, i want 1st example same but when i mouse hover into links change bottom border colour like demo 2. in second demo menu background colour change but i want bottom border colour change... is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few modifications needs to be done. HTML / CSS / jQuery

Go to your HTML flle and update the all the a tags in `<li>`s' of `<ul id="example-one">`. These a tags should have attribute "rel" and this attribute has the value of your bottom border color. Like demo 2 (you may see how it is in html file).

After adding "rel" attribute.

```
<ul class="group" id="example-one">
            <li class="current_page_item">
                <a href="#" rel="#C6AA01">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a rel="#fe4902" href="#">Buy Tickets</a></li>
            <li><a rel="#A41322" href="#">Group Sales</a></li>
            <li><a rel="#C6AA01" href="#">Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a rel="#900" href="#">The Show</a></li>
            <li><a rel="#D40229" href="#">Videos</a></li>
            <li><a rel="#1B9B93" href="#">Photos</a></li>
            <li><a rel="#8DC91E" href="#">Magic Shop</a></li>
</ul>
```

then go to your css file and remove the background color property. if you didn't remove this background colour, there will be color transition animation from "#magic-line" background colour to "rel" colour value.
accoding to your requirement make sure to remove it.

**CSS**

```
#magic-line { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 2px; 
    //background: #fe4902; - remove this.
}
```

In your jQuery file please update this code:

```
$magicLine
        .width($(".current_page_item").width())
        .css("left", $(".current_page_item a").position().left)
        .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width())
    // add below code
    .data("origColor", $(".current_page_item a").attr("rel")); 

 $("#example-one li").find("a").hover(function() {
        $el = $(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();

        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth,

        // add below code   
        backgroundColor: $el.attr("rel")        
        });
    }, function() {
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth"),

            // add below code
            backgroundColor: $magicLine.data("origColor")

        });    
    });

    $(".current_page_item a").mouseenter();
```

Comment: thanks :) its working perfect.. i got my solution... thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `rel` attribute on each `a` tag, which is going to be the border colour:

```
<ul class="group" id="example-one">
    <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#" rel="#fe4902">Home</a></li>
    <li><a rel="#fe4902" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a rel="#A41322" href="#">Buy Tickets</a></li>
    <li><a rel="#C6AA01" href="#">Group Sales</a></li>
    <li><a rel="#D40229" href="#">The Show</a></li>
    <li><a rel="#98CEAA" href="#">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a rel="#1B9B93" href="#">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a rel="#8DC91E" href="#">Magic Shop</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then you need to store the original colour value.

So after you get the `OrigWidth` of `$magicLine`, you need

```
    .data("origColor", $('.current_page_item a').attr("rel"));
```

On the hover function you need to grab the value of the `rel` attribute for the item you're hovering over.

```
      backgroundColor: $el.attr("rel")
```

Then on mouse-out, you need to set the border back to the original colour

```
        backgroundColor : $magicLine.data("origColor")
```